# What is meant by “genes at the trunk of the evolutionary tree”?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, bioinformatics, cancer

Recently I went through a [paper about hepatocellular carcinoma](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v46/n1/full/ng.2847.html) in which they talked about trunk genes (p. 26, second paragraph):

> Branching tumor evolution complicates efforts to implement
>   personalized medicine and suggests that targeted therapies might be
>   directed to genes that are mutated at the trunk of the evolutionary
>   tree. Transposons provide powerful tools for identifying trunk genes,
>   as insertions in trunk genes are more likely to be associated with a
>   higher number of sequencing reads.

I really don’t understand what are the trunk genes. Can anyone please explain them clearly.

Thank you

Comment: I've tidied up you question a little and given focus to the key concept at issue — the "genes at the trunk of the evolutionary tree".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the article is using a **phylogenetic tree** to explain the stages of how the tumor has evolved.

According to **[Nature.com](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v13/n11/box/nrg3317_BX1.html)** >>

> All trees have a **shared 'trunk'**, which represents the complement of
>   mutations shared by all malignant cells within the cancer.

Or simplified by **[Britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/science/phylogenetic-tree)** >>

> Phylogenetic tree, also called Dendrogram, a diagram showing the
>   evolutionary interrelations of a group of organisms derived from a
>   common ancestral form. The *ancestor* is in the **tree “trunk”**; organisms
>   that have arisen from it are placed at the ends of tree “branches.”

For a visual representation, this is a phylogenetic tree for evolution of breast cancer >>

[image: Tree]

**Image Source**: **[Phylogenetic Cancer Trees](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v13/n11/box/nrg3317_BX1.html)**

Comment: My first few readings of the sentence, I thought the article meant the ontogenetic tree -- that is, the mutation occurred early in the life of that specific individual.  From the word "evolutionary", though, I think you are right.  Still, the confusion is a warning to technical writers to use metaphors only very carefully.

Comment: @Malvolio I had the similar confusion, although upon reading the abstract the OP has provided, I am pretty sure the **trunk genes** they have mentioned in the context of evolutionary trees is what I have answered. Needless to say, I totally agree with you about the careful use of these terms.

Comment: @user3351523 My pleasure. Glad I could help.